# split html text in 2 paragraphs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, string

hi i have a html text like this:

```
aaa dafjsld dslajfk òsal asfòljd <a href="ciao.com">aa aa</a> adsfsadfsadfs
```

i want to split it in 2 paragraphs. but i don't want to generate this situation:

```
<p>aaa dafjsld dslajfk òsal asfòljd <a href="ciao.com">aa</p><p> aa</a> adsfsadfsadfs</p>
```

how can i check if the split involves any tags and avoid it?

thanks

Comment: At which position do you want to add a new <p> tag? What is the logic for selecting the position(i.e are you looking for a pattern OR string length?)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`simple_format`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#M001751) for this, assuming your text is formatted correctly. Your link text should end inside the paragraph, not on the next one, so I've modified it slightly:

```
 aaa dafjsld dslajfk òsal asfòljd <a href='ciao.com'>aa</a>

 aa adsfsadfsadfs
```

This will output:

`<p>aaa dafjsld dslajfk òsal asfòljd <a href='ciao.com'>aa</a></p><p>aa adsfsadfsadfs</p>` or something to that effect if you pass it to `simple_format`.

Comment: I think he wanted to wrap text, not do something similar to Markdown, but thanks for telling me about `simple_format`.

Comment: Ah yes, documentation. I should link to that.

Answer (score 2):

Use 'HtmlSlicer' gem for Rails.

Put this line in your Gemfile:

```
gem 'html_slicer'
```

Then bundle:

```
% bundle
```

Gem acts much more complex, and it can't split text by number of parts.
Anyway due to your local task:

```
content = "aaa dafjsld dslajfk òsal asfòljd <a href=\"ciao.com\">aa aa</a> adsfsadfsadfs"
split = HtmlSlicer::Interface.new(content, {:slice => {:maximum => 30}})
split
=> "aaa dafjsld dslajfk òsal asfòljd <a href=\"ciao.com\">aa</a>"
split.slice!(2)
=> "<a href=\"ciao.com\"> aa</a> adsfsadfsadfs"
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing more about the problem, the most general solution will probably involve Hpricot or REXML. That'll make sure that any nested tags are handled correctly. You can walk the node list and decide where to create paragraphs.